# Accessing cookie set by back-end on another domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, cross-domain, document

If my backend is on abc.com and sets a cookie in the frontend which is on xyz.com then I am not able to access the cookie on the frontend using document.cookie , is there a work-around for this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

If it was possible then Evil-Hacker.com could read the cookies from Your-Bank.com and gain access to your bank account.

Cookies are accessible, directly, only if the `Domain` parameter of the cookie matches a segment of the domain of the page trying to read them. (e.g. `foo.example.com` could read a cookie set for `example.com`). Top-level domains (like `.com`) are excluded from this.

An Ajax request, with the `withCredentials` flag set, could make a request to the domain the served the cookies (this would need permission via CORS with a pre-flight). A server-side script on that domain could then read the cookie and echo it back in the body of the response where JS could read it. Obviously this requires the domain the cookie belongs to to co-operate by providing such a webservice.

Comment: But the cookie set by my back-end(abc.com) on the frontend is not a part of the request I am sending from the front-end(xyz.com) to my back-end. I am using fetch in the frontend with credentials: "include". I am using express in the back-end and my req.cookies is an empty object.

Comment: If you are making a request to `abc.com` then `fetch` will include the cookies for `abc.com` and not `xyz.com`