# Next.js Middleware Can't Access JWT Cookies in Production with Different Domains

Tags: cookies, middleware, next.js13

I am developing an application with Next.js for the frontend and Node.js with Express.js for the backend. I use a middleware in Next.js for JWT-based authentication. In my local development environment, where both the frontend and backend run on localhost but on different ports (frontend on http://localhost:3000 and backend on http://localhost:8001), everything works as expected.

However, when deployed in production, my frontend is on https://frontend.com and the backend on https://backend.com:8001. In this environment, the middleware cannot access the JWT token stored in cookies, preventing proper authentication and authorization.

Here is the relevant code from my Next.js middleware:

```
// next.js middleware
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { jwtVerify } from "jose";
// ... other imports ...

const secret = process.env.SECRET;

async function verify(token, secret) {
    const { payload } = await jwtVerify(token, new TextEncoder().encode(secret));
    return payload;
}

export default async function middleware(request) {
    const url = request.url;
    const nextUrl = request.nextUrl.clone();
    // ... middleware logic ...

    // Example function for verifying access
    const checkAccess = async (allowedRole) => {
        const jwt = request.cookies.get('token')?.value;
        if (!jwt) {
            nextUrl.pathname = '/';
            return NextResponse.rewrite(nextUrl);
        }
        
        try {
            const verification = await verify(jwt, secret);
            if (verification.Role === allowedRole) {
                return NextResponse.next();
            } else {
                throw new Error("ACCESS DENIED");
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // Error handling
            // ...
        }
    };

    // Role verification
    if (url.includes("/dashboard/teacher")) {
        return checkAccess('Teacher');
    }
    // ... other verifications ...
};

return NextResponse.next();


This is the cookie configuration for the login on the backend:

function getDomainURL(){
    switch (process.env.NODE_ENV){
        case ('production'):
            return '.frontend.com';
        case ('development'):
            return 'localhost'
    }
}

const COOKIE_OPTIONS = {
    httpOnly: true,
    path: "/",
    sameSite: 'None', // Permitir cookies en solicitudes entre diferentes orígenes
    secure: true, // Requerido cuando sameSite es 'None'
    domain: getDomainURL()
};

 res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", serialize("token", token, COOKIE_OPTIONS));

function getOriginURL(){
    switch (process.env.NODE_ENV){
        case ('production'):
            return 'https://www.frontend.com';
        case ('development'):
            return 'http://localhost:3000'
    }
}

let originURL = getOriginURL()

app.use(cors({
    origin: originURL,
    credentials: true,
}))
```

The middleware cannot access the token in the cookie when the backend is on the domain https://backend.com:8001. This prevents the middleware from functioning correctly to protect the routes.

How can I configure my Next.js application and/or my backend so that the middleware can access the cookies correctly despite being on different domains?

Any guidance or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you won't be able to access the cookies from your request because the domains are different.

Here's a scenario where the opposite happens, but it also applies to your case.

[Accessing cookie set by back-end on another domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70698143/accessing-cookie-set-by-back-end-on-another-domain)

Regards!